# Trying to install a Dll from legacy win 2003 server to 2008r2 server and failing

Tags: dll, asp-classic, registry, iis-6, iis-7.5

I'm moving a legacy application from a windows 2003 32 bit IIS 6 server to a windows 2008 r2 IIS 7.5 server.

Ultimately, I'm getting a `Server.CreateObject(customobject)` failed on the app.

Researching this, it seems that the object's DLL needs to be registered with the server.

I went back to the old server, found the dll by running `regedit`, it was located in C:\windows\system32 folder.

So I moved it over and am trying to register it using `regsvr32.exe` from the `SysWOW64` directory.  However, I'm getting two errors depending on what I do:

The command:

```
regsvr32.exe "I:\mypath\mymodule.dll"
```

generates

> The module "I:\mypath\mymodule.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Ok, so lets try the options:

```
regsvr32.exe /n /i "I:\mypath\mymodule.dll"
```

throws

> The module "I:\mypath\mymodule.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllInstall was not found.

I have no idea what else I can try, I don't think I have the source to the dll, any suggestions please?

Comment: Rather than just downgrading a question would the down-grader please leave a comment as to why?

Comment: It's kind of weird, this got downvoted almost as soon as i posted it, certainly before somebody would've been able to comprehend it.  I do still need help with this if anybody has some more stuff to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out,

I had to get .net fw 2.0 sp2 on there and use regasm.exe to register the dll.